# T-crossing in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path

I'm basically trying to trace the isometric view of a technical drawing in inkscape. I do know, that joining nodes on different paths is only possible, when the two nodes in question are the end nodes of the respective paths and the two paths are combined into one. I need to make T-crossings of more than one line segment, which form a perfect outer angle. Is this somehow possible?

[image]

In this picture, the upper right corner of the triangle forms a perfect angle with the two adjacent lines. The lower left corner, where an extra line segment is added doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an Inkscape user. However, in general you need to rethink how paths are connected or interact. All vector software I'm aware of won't allow the joining of 3 paths to a single anchor point.

So, rather than drawing the lower left path as a separate path, it may help to rework how the corner is formed with a *single* path:

[image]

Of course I don't know the entire image, so this is merely an example. The gist is to create the *outer* corners with your paths and draw separate paths for *inner* paths if needed. Don't try and form the outer portion of a shape with separate paths.

Comment: Just to say, that technique also works in Inkscape, and probably every vector image editor in existence.

Comment: That was my solution as well. +1 for the video.